# Placing K knights in an nxn board such that no two attack each other

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, spoj

This is a [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CODCHESS/) from spoj

> A and B are playing a very interesting variant of the ancient Indian game 'shatranj(also known as chess)' on a 'maidaan'(chessboard) n×n in size.
>
> They take turns to put game pieces called 'ghoda'(knight) so that no two 'ghodas'(knights) could threat each other.
>
> A 'ghoda' located in square (a,b) can threat squares (a+1,b+2),(a-1,b+2),(a+1,b-2),(a-1,b-2),(a+2,b-1),(a+2,b+1),(a-2,b-1),(a-2,b+1).
>
> The player who can't put a new 'ghoda' during his move loses. Find out which player wins considering that both players play optimally well and A starts.

I cannot use brute force as n is very large, Is there an `O(n) or O(1)` algorithm for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: consider a strategy when one player answers the moves of his opponent by central symmetry. For which $n$ does it work for the second player? When it doesn't work for the second player, can the first one use the strategy instead?

Comment: so if n is even always 2nd players wins. But what strategy can 1st players use in case of odd?

Comment: @Alex, he can use the same strategy with a very, *very* minor adjustment.

Comment: I think I got it. For odd n first player can place a knight at the center. Then he can use the same strategy.

Comment: @Alex Yes, exactly.